# guardar datos a un arraylist de un resultset

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, web

espero me puedan ayudar estoy tratando de hacer que me retorne un lista desde  la base de datos a travez de un resultset pero no logro conseguir espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias

```
public ArrayList<BeanNivelLlenado> consultarNivel(){
        ArrayList<BeanNivelLlenado> niveles=new ArrayList<BeanNivelLlenado>();
        try {
            conn=this.getConexion();
            st=conn.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery("select * from nivel;");
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();


            while (rs.next()) {

                HashMap row = new HashMap();
                niveles.add(row);
                for(int i=1; i<=columns; i++){
                    row.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i));
                  }
                return niveles;
            }
            this.cerrarConexion();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return niveles; 
    }
```

es un select de un html y quisiera saber cual seria el error, al llamar a esa lista llenada

```
<%
    ArrayList<BeanNivelLlenado> listaNivel= (ArrayList<BeanNivelLlenado>)request.getAttribute("listaNivel");
%>
<SELECT NAME="selNivel" SIZE=1 style="width:120px;text-align:center;">
                        <OPTION>Seleccione</OPTION>
                        <%for(BeanNivelLlenado nivel: listaNivel){%>
                        <option ><%= nivel.getNivel()%></option>
                        <%} %>
                </SELECT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
public ArrayList<BeanNivelLlenado> consultarNivel()
{
    List<BeanNivelLlenado> niveles= new ArrayList<BeanNivelLlenado>();
    try {
        conn=this.getConexion();
        st=conn.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("select * from nivel;");
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            // aca tienes que crear un BEAN NIVELES
            BeanNivelLlenado bnll = new BeanNivelLlenado();
            bnll.setNivel(rs.getInt("nivel"));
            bnll.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
            // y así sucesivamente con todos los campos del 
            // bean BeanNivelLlenado
            niveles.add(bnll);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        this.cerrarConexion();
    }
    return niveles; 
}
```

Comment: gracias me sirvio pero surgio un problema nose si puedas ayudarme, estoy tratando de llevar esos datos a un select, pero creo el error es llamar un campo como value cuando todos son de tipo string y no un tipo number             <SELECT NAME="selNivel" SIZE=1 style="width:120px;text-align:center;">
      <OPTION>Seleccione</OPTION>
      <%for(BeanNivelLlenado nivel: listaNivel){%>
      <option value="<%=nivel.getIdNivel() %>"><%= nivel.getNivel()%></option>
      <%} %>
    </SELECT>

Comment: Hola @JavierMedina
Es difícil entender el problema desde un comentario. Te sugiero formular otra pregunta.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

// ejemplo generico por si te sirve:

public ArrayList Lista(String s_sql){

```
  ArrayList<Object> datos = new ArrayList<Object>();

  try{
      Conexion con = new Conexion();
      Connection cn = null;          
      cn = con.conectar();
      if(cn != null){
          Statement st;
          ResultSet rs;
          ResultSetMetaData md;
          st = cn.createStatement();              
          rs = st.executeQuery(s_sql);
          md = rs.getMetaData();
          int columnas = md.getColumnCount();
          while(rs.next()){
              Object dato = new Object[columnas];
              for (int i = 1; i <= columnas; i++) {                      
                  dato = rs.getObject(i);
              }
              datos.add(dato);
          }
      }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
  }           
  return datos;
```

}